# Resizing Children in SplitLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt

I'm having an issue resizing the child widget inside a SplitLayoutPanel. I have a table in the South region of my layout. When I drag the splitter to increase the size the table doesn't resize. It stays at it's fixed height which causes white space under neath the table. When I shrink the South panel the table appears to "hide" behind the footer div image I have at the bottom of the Window. Is there a way to resize the table as the panel increases/decreases in size?

How I my South Panel is laid out.  The "South" panel is real just the center panel filling out the rest of the space.
That center panel has a SimplePanel.
Attached to the SimplePanel is a LayoutPanel. I'm using that because there is a button bar above the table and SimplePanel only takes one Widget so I had to nest the widgets inside something else.
LayoutPanel's height and width are set to 100%
I'm guessing what needs to happen is the layout panel height needs to adjust. I'm not sure.
If need be I can post code. I'm also using the MVP/Activity/Places method

**UPDATE**

SplitLayoutPanel UI:

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel>
   <g:north size='250'>
    . . .
   </g:north size='250'>
   <g:center>
     <g:SimplePanel ui:field="south"/>
   </g:center>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

Table Layout:

```
<g:LayoutPanel width="100%" height="100%">
  <g:layer top='0px' height='125px'>
     ButtonBar is here
  </g:layer>
  <g:layer top='30px' bottom='5px'>
    <g:HorizontalPanel width="100%" height="100%">
       <table:CustomTable height="500"/>
    </g:HorizontalPanel>
  </g:layer>
</g:LayoutPanel>
```

The Table Widget is placed into the center panel of the SplitLayoutPanel.

Comment: Instead of describing how your panels are laid out, why not just post the UiBinder XML?

Comment: Ok I can post the Uibinder. I didn't at first because I code on a different comp then what I research problems.